# Открытие внешних ссылок в WebView

Tags: android, java

Вот код WebView:

```
ww = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.ww);
WebSettings webSettings = ww.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

ww.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
ww.setWebViewClient(new MainWebClient(this));        
        ww.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + Integer.toString(MainActivity.reg_num) + "/index.html");
```

В index.html есть внешняя ссылка, мне нужно ее открывать. Сейчас когда я нажимаю на нее, ничего не происходит.

Код MainWebClient:

```
package com.test.regions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    Context context;

    public MainWebClient(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, то что нужно, проверьте:

- [WebView: Activate JavaScript and Open Links Inside](http://www.androidsnippets.com/webview-activate-javascript-and-open-links-inside)
- [Android WebView touch event link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951492/android-webview-touch-event-link)